# Sort array based on frequency of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an array which has duplicate data. I want to sort it based on frequency (highest duplicates element first)and then remove the duplicates.

I tried the below code,its throwing different order.

```js
var arr=[
    {name: "Manage AAA Devices", sys_id: "7b491aad371adb003ef7a9c2b3990e22"},
    {name: "", sys_id: ""},
    {name: "Manage AAA - ISE Admin Functions", sys_id: "dc5f99a2dbb2b74019d81ffa68961933"},
    {name: "Manage AAA Devices", sys_id: "7b491aad371adb003ef7a9c2b3990e22"},
    {name: "Manage AAA - ISE Admin Functions", sys_id: "dc5f99a2dbb2b74019d81ffa68961933"},
    {name: "SNOW Change Request", sys_id: "325b08913783d6c4f4f4c97a43990e90"},
    {name: "", sys_id: ""},
    {name: "Manage AAA - ISE Admin Functions", sys_id: "dc5f99a2dbb2b74019d81ffa68961933"},
    {name: "Manage AAA - ISE Admin Functions", sys_id: "dc5f99a2dbb2b74019d81ffa68961933"},
    {name: "Incident Request", sys_id: "3ee543f61b363740f713ed7b2f4bcbc0"}
];

console.log(arr.reduce((x, y) => {
  if (x[y.name]) {
    x[y.name]++;
    return x;
  } else {
    var z = {};
    z[y.name] = 1;
    return Object.assign(x, z);
  }
}, {}))
```

Comment: where is `y.fruit` coming from? and based on which key are the duplicates identified?

Comment: Well, now you have fixed the property name, you seem to have a working version :) Just keep in mind, that the order on an object is not specified, and the result you have is an object, not an array anymore, but maybe now you can sort with the property of `name` against your reduced set :)

Comment: @Icepickle sorry I have posted different array.Please check my updated code now.Still the order is not correct.

Comment: @krish I updated my comment, hopefully that helps you enough

Comment: How big will your real data become, krish? Cause the answer you accepted is O(2N), so as your data grows, the time it will take to sort will grow [exponentially](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/265/exponential.html). You can try it with the seed generator I provided to see the differences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the optimal solution, but you can use it as a start:

```js
var arr = [{
    "name": "Manage AAA Devices",
    "sys_id": "7b491aad371adb003ef7a9c2b3990e22"
  },
  {
    "name": "",
    "sys_id": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Manage AAA - ISE Admin Functions",
    "sys_id": "dc5f99a2dbb2b74019d81ffa68961933"
  },
  {
    "name": "Manage AAA Devices",
    "sys_id": "7b491aad371adb003ef7a9c2b3990e22"
  },
  {
    "name": "Manage AAA - ISE Admin Functions",
    "sys_id": "dc5f99a2dbb2b74019d81ffa68961933"
  },
  {
    "name": "SNOW Change Request",
    "sys_id": "325b08913783d6c4f4f4c97a43990e90"
  },
  {
    "name": "",
    "sys_id": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Manage AAA - ISE Admin Functions",
    "sys_id": "dc5f99a2dbb2b74019d81ffa68961933"
  },
  {
    "name": "Manage AAA - ISE Admin Functions",
    "sys_id": "dc5f99a2dbb2b74019d81ffa68961933"
  },
  {
    "name": "Incident Request",
    "sys_id": "3ee543f61b363740f713ed7b2f4bcbc0"
  }
];

const noOfOccurencies = arr.reduce((x, y) => {
  if (x[y.name]) {
    x[y.name]++;
    return x;
  } else {
    var z = {};
    z[y.name] = 1;
    return Object.assign(x, z);
  }
}, {})

console.log(noOfOccurencies);

// Order an array of objects based on another array order
// https://gist.github.com/ecarter/1423674
function mapOrder(array, order, key) {
  array.sort(function(a, b) {
    var A = a[key],
      B = b[key];

    if (order.indexOf(A) > order.indexOf(B)) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  });
  return array;
};

// sort noOfOccurencies
const itemOrder = Object.keys(noOfOccurencies).sort(function(a, b) {
  return noOfOccurencies[a] - noOfOccurencies[b]
})
// reverse noOfOccurencies (*highest duplicates element first*)
itemOrder.reverse();

console.log(itemOrder);

// order the original array based on itemOrder
let ordered_array = mapOrder(arr, itemOrder, 'name');

// remove duplicates from the new array ordered
const noDuplicatesArr = ordered_array.filter((v, i, a) => a.findIndex(t => (t.name === v.name)) === i)

console.log(noDuplicatesArr);
```

Comment: Once you found the length, there really shouldn't be any need to re-iterate the original array, especially if the rest are simply dupes

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [
    {name: "Manage AAA Devices", sys_id: "7b491aad371adb003ef7a9c2b3990e22"},
    {name: "", sys_id: ""},
    {name: "Manage AAA - ISE Admin Functions", sys_id: "dc5f99a2dbb2b74019d81ffa68961933"},
    {name: "Manage AAA Devices", sys_id: "7b491aad371adb003ef7a9c2b3990e22"},
    {name: "Manage AAA - ISE Admin Functions", sys_id: "dc5f99a2dbb2b74019d81ffa68961933"},
    {name: "SNOW Change Request", sys_id: "325b08913783d6c4f4f4c97a43990e90"},
    {name: "", sys_id: ""},
    {name: "Manage AAA - ISE Admin Functions", sys_id: "dc5f99a2dbb2b74019d81ffa68961933"},
    {name: "Manage AAA - ISE Admin Functions", sys_id: "dc5f99a2dbb2b74019d81ffa68961933"},
    {name: "Incident Request", sys_id: "3ee543f61b363740f713ed7b2f4bcbc0"},
];

function sortByFrequency(arrayWithDuplicates) {
    let tempArray = [];
    let temp = [];

    arrayWithDuplicates.forEach((item) => {
            temp.push(JSON.stringify(item));
        }
    );

    (Array(...new Set(temp))).forEach((x) => {
        tempArray.push(arrayWithDuplicates.filter((y) => {
            return x === JSON.stringify(y);
        }));
    });

    tempArray.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.length - b.length;
    });

    temp = [];
    tempArray.forEach((item) => {
        temp.push({name: item[0].name, frequency: item.length});
    });

    return temp.reverse();
}

console.log(sortByFrequency(arr));
```

Comment: there is quite an overhead with stringifying the full object you want to compare, especially with the double iteration. For the current size it is fine, but depending how his source array might grow, that might cost some time

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest might simply be to keep the original item as part of the dictionary you are creating and afterwards you can simply use that dictionary to do the sorting. The dictionary will anyhow only have the 1 item in there anymore and it will have an item count.

So you would have a slightly changed `reduce` function

```
function reduceWithCount( arr, prop ) {
  return arr.reduce( (agg, item) => {
    const key = item[prop];
    if (!agg[key]) {
      agg[key] = { count: 0, item };
    }
    agg[key].count++;
    return agg;
  }, {});
}
```

And to create a new array from that, which is sorted by the frequency you recorded, you can just map the items back and use the previously saved count from the dictionary object

```
function createArrayFromObject( countedDictionary, prop ) {
  return Object.keys( countedDictionary )
    .map( key => countedDictionary[key].item )
    .sort( (a, b) => countedDictionary[b[prop]].count - countedDictionary[a[prop]].count );
}
```

It would however mean that using those functions, you would have to pass along the key twice, but I don't think that's much of an overhead.

I changed the code of the snippet slightly so that it doesn't use your original array, but a randomly generated one instead to see how it would handle 50.000 entries instead.

As long as you don't have 50000 different names in your original array, it would be fine with the simple dictionary lookup.

```js
const seed = {
  'Manage AAA Devices': '7b491aad371adb003ef7a9c2b3990e22',
  '': '',
  'Manage AAA - ISE Admin Functions': 'dc5f99a2dbb2b74019d81ffa68961933',
  'SNOW Change Request': '325b08913783d6c4f4f4c97a43990e90',
  'Incident Request': '3ee543f61b363740f713ed7b2f4bcbc0'
};

const seedKeys = Object.keys( seed );
const arr = [...new Array(50000)].map( _ => {
  let name = seedKeys[parseInt(Math.random() * seedKeys.length)];
  return { name, sysId: seed[name] };
} );

console.log(`array generated with ${arr.length} items`);

function reduceWithCount( arr, prop ) {
  return arr.reduce( (agg, item) => {
    const key = item[prop];
    if (!agg[key]) {
      agg[key] = { count: 0, item };
    }
    agg[key].count++;
    return agg;
  }, {});
}

function createArrayFromObject( countedDictionary, prop ) {
  return Object.keys( countedDictionary )
    .map( key => countedDictionary[key].item )
    .sort( (a, b) => countedDictionary[b[prop]].count - countedDictionary[a[prop]].count );
}

console.time('removeAndSort');
const removedDuplicates = reduceWithCount( arr, 'name' );
const sortedArray = createArrayFromObject( removedDuplicates, 'name' );
console.timeEnd('removeAndSort');
console.log( removedDuplicates );
console.log( sortedArray );
```